nodejs sequelize default to uuid
I am using a nodejs backend with sequelize.
Right now when I make a model like
import { sequelize } from "../db/sequelize.mjs";
import { DataTypes } from "sequelize";

const User = sequelize.define(
  "User",
  {
    username: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
  },
  {
    tableName: "users", // Specify the actual table name
  }
);
export { User };


the id comes through like 1 or 2 but I want sequelize to default all models to use uuid
instead of typing that in each model I want to type that as the default value in the sequelize config here
import { Sequelize } from "sequelize";

// the config for the sequelize connection to the psql db
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  dialect: "postgres",
  username: "user",
  host: "postgresql",
  database: "mydatabase",
  password: "password",
  port: 5432,
  define: {
    timestamps: true,
    // by default sequelize is camelcase (i.e. 'createdAt') and psql cant handle camelcase
    //   we want to default all db names to use underscores as well (i.e. 'created_at')
    underscored: true,
  },
});

export { sequelize };

I am struggling to find documentation on this

You could try to define models using classes and then  just define something like RootModel where you can define id with uuid type and descent each model from this class.
